# Numberformat Google Spreadsheet API v4 Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am reading a Google Spreadsheet like described in the Java Quickstart

https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java

The Quickstart explaines how to read data from a give range

```
.....
String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
    .get(spreadsheetId, range)
    .execute();

List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);

for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
    List row = values.get(i);
    double l1 = nf.parse(row.get(1).toString()).doubleValue();
....
```

As you can see I am reading double values from the response

I expect a dedicated format for the double values (e.g. 12,34 instead of 12.34)

Can I already pass as a parameter to the request the number format I expect? 
Something like:

```
service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).myNumberFormat("##,#####").execute()
```

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 1):

The response you get from the spreadsheet is, by default, already formatted the way it is in the spreadsheet.  Your call to `nf.parse(..)` is translating from that formatted version into a native java type, so you lose the formatting.

If you want the raw values directly (so you don't need to do parsing locally), you can set the [`valueRenderOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) to `UNFORMATTED_VALUE`.  See [this sample](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/reading#read_a_single_range_with_rendering_options) for more information.

I'm not too sure exactly what question you're asking, since your code sample already gets a formatted version and you're explicitly dropping that formatting by parsing it.

If you'd like a specific kind of formatting that's not already in your spreadsheet, then retrieve the raw value (using the UNFORMATTED_VALUE valueRenderOption) and use your NumberFormat locally to translate to that format.  Alternately, set your desired formatting in the spreadsheet and just retrieve the values and don't re-parse them.